# Read Json files from Azure blob using python?

Tags: python, json, azure-blob-storage

I need to read a JSON file from a blob container in Azure for doing some transformation on top of the JSON Files. I have seen few documentation and StackOverflow answers and developed a python code that will read the files from the blob.

I have tried the below script from one of the Stackoverflow answers to read JSON file but I get the below error

"TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or byte array, not BytesIO"

I am new to python programming so not sure of the issue in the code. I tried with download_stream.content_as_text() but the file doesnt read the file without any error.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from pandas import json_normalize
import json

filename = "sample.json"

container_name="test"
constr = ""

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(constr)
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
streamdownloader=blob_client.download_blob()

stream = BytesIO()
streamdownloader.download_to_stream(stream)
# with open(stream) as j:
#      contents = json.loads(j)
fileReader = json.loads(stream)

print(filereader)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `readall`function. Please try this code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import json

filename = "sample.json"

container_name="test"
constr = ""

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(constr)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()

fileReader = json.loads(streamdownloader.readall())
print(fileReader)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: is there any way to read multiple files based on a pattern using the above code. TIA.

Comment: If the JSON is gzipped, use `import gzip` and `json.loads(gzip.decompress(streamdownloader.readall()))` to prevent `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`.  ([Credits.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61364994/812102))